# How do you print a key of a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a dictionary:

```
dictionary1 = {'test':'output','test2':'output2'}
```

How would I be able to print the key, `test`, on the screen?

I only want **one** of the keys at a time, **not** all of them.

By the way, not literally, by doing `print('test')`, I mean how do you print the key of any dictionary?

Like is there something like this:

```
#pseudocode
x = dictionary1.keys()[0]
>>> print(x)
'test'
```

I do not want to sort the dictionary that I'm actually using in my program.

Comment: i'll edit my q to make things clearer. @ScottHunter

Comment: Do you mean `.keys()`?

Comment: probably. if I do `print(dictionary1.keys('test'))`, will that print out `'test'`? @SimeonVisser

Comment: A dictionary can have any number of keys, including zero, so your question currently doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Re your updated question: No, there's no guarantee what order the keys of a dictionary are in. A `collections.OrderedDict`, which is very similar to a regular dictionary, will remember the order in which keys were added to it, so using one might be useful to you and not require sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary may have any number of keys, 0+.  To print them all (if any) in sorted order, you could

```
for key in sorted(dictionary1):
    print(key)
```

If you don't care about the order (i.e you're fine with a random-looking order), remove the `sorted` call.

If you want to be selective (e.g only print keys that are sequences of length 4, so that in your example `test` would be printed but `test2` wouldn't):

```
for key in sorted(dictionary1):
    try:
        if len(key) == 4:
            print(key)
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

If you want to print only *one* such key, add a `break` after the `print`.

There are at least 347 other things you could mean by your extremely vague question, but I tried to field the ones that seem most likely... if that's not enough for you, edit your question to make it **much** more precise!-)

Added: the edit only said the OP wants to print only one key and do no sorting, so it remains a mystery **how** that one key is to be picked (I suspect there's a misunderstanding -- as if `dict` keys had a specific order, which of course in Python they don't, and the OP wants "the first one", which just can't be pinned down -- `OrderedDict` is a very different [and alas inevitably slower] beast, but `dict`s what the OP's showing).

So if the goal is to print "any one key, no matter which one" (and it is known that `thedict` is not empty):

```
print(next(iter(thedict)))
```

is the simplest, most direct way -- a `dict` is iterable, yielding its keys in arbitrary order; `iter` returns an iterator on its iterable argument; and `next` returns the first (first in arbitrary order means an arbitrary one of course) item of its iterator argument.

If it's possible for `thedict` to be empty, and nothing must be printed in that case, just add a guard:

```
if thedict: print(next(iter(thedict)))
```

This will print nothing for an empty dictionary, the only key for a dictionary with length 1, an arbitrary key for a dictionary with length greater than 1.

Comment: Yes, but not precisely enough -- **how** do you want to pick `test` rather than `test1` to be shown?  Keys in a dict are in no order, so, do you just want to show a random one?  I'll edit the A to show how to do the latter but I suspect you actually and wrongly believe keys are in some specific order and want "the first one" -- there's just no such thing!

Comment: No, I know that dicts dont have a specific order, however, my question is this. If you have a dict `dict1 = {'test1':25}`, how can I print `'test1'`?

Comment: @interwebz my answer as I just edited it will do that -- print an arbitrary one of `dict1`'s keys, so the only one if there's only one:-).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find a key associated with a specific value you can do

```
keys = [key for key in d if d[key] == value]
print(keys)
```